# XML delete elements base on match

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I like to remove elements base on the sub-element match.
Example of `file.xml`:

```
 <entry>
  <title>TEST1</title>
  <profile>
    <title>Default</title>
    <pid>
      <pidNumber>1880</pidNumber>
      <ContentType>PMT</ContentType>
      <isScrambled>0</isScrambled>
    </pid>
    <pid>
      <pidNumber>201</pidNumber>
      <ContentType>Video</ContentType>
      <isScrambled>0</isScrambled>
    </pid>
    <pid>
      <pidNumber>301</pidNumber>
      <ContentType>Audio</ContentType>
      <isScrambled>0</isScrambled>
    </pid>
    <pid>
      <pidNumber>302</pidNumber>
      <ContentType>Audio</ContentType>
      <isScrambled>0</isScrambled>
    </pid>
    <pid>
      <pidNumber>310</pidNumber>
      <ContentType>Audio</ContentType>
      <isScrambled>0</isScrambled>
    </pid>
  </profile>
</entry>
```

As you can see there lot of PIDS value (201,301,302-310) I want to remove all the pids that matches from 302-310. Here is my code, but I get error.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse("file.xml").getroot()
regex = r"[3][0-1][02-9]"
getpid = root.iter("pid")

for item in getpid:
    pidnum = item.find('.//pidNumber')
    pidnum = pidnum.text
    match = re.findall(regex, pidnum)
    match = ''.join(match)
    if pidnum == match:
        ET.dump(item)
        item.remove(getpid)

tree = ET(root)
tree.write("out.xml")
```

Error I get:

> self._children.remove(element)
>   ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

How to solve? I think I'm close.
Thank you for viewing and help.

Comment: I suspect the correct operation is `getpid.remove(item)`

Comment: hi barny, still error `getpid.remove(item)
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'remove'`

Comment: I edited: `getpid = root.getiterator("pid")` that works. but some reason i still see the pids into new file "out.xml"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to remove all the pids that matches from 302-310.

I think your regex logic is flawed. If you had a pidNumber that was `319` (or `312`, `313`, etc.), those pid elements would also be removed.

Also, instead of removing the `pid` completely, your code just removes its children leaving an empty `pid` element. (Maybe that's desired, but it didn't sound like it based on "*I like to remove elements base on the sub-element match.*".)

Instead of using `getroot()`, try using `find()` to get the `profile` element. This is the parent of `pid` which is what we'll need to remove the `pid` itself.

And instead of using a regex to match the `pidNumber`, just do a basic comparison.

Example...

**file.xml** (added additional `pid` elements for testing)

```
<entry>
    <title>TEST1</title>
    <profile>
        <title>Default</title>
        <pid>
            <pidNumber>1880</pidNumber>
            <ContentType>PMT</ContentType>
            <isScrambled>0</isScrambled>
        </pid>
        <pid>
            <pidNumber>201</pidNumber>
            <ContentType>Video</ContentType>
            <isScrambled>0</isScrambled>
        </pid>
        <pid>
            <pidNumber>301</pidNumber>
            <ContentType>Audio</ContentType>
            <isScrambled>0</isScrambled>
        </pid>
        <pid>
            <pidNumber>302</pidNumber>
            <ContentType>Audio</ContentType>
            <isScrambled>0</isScrambled>
        </pid>
        <pid>
            <pidNumber>303</pidNumber>
            <ContentType>Audio</ContentType>
            <isScrambled>0</isScrambled>
        </pid>
        <pid>
            <pidNumber>309</pidNumber>
            <ContentType>Audio</ContentType>
            <isScrambled>0</isScrambled>
        </pid>
        <pid>
            <pidNumber>310</pidNumber>
            <ContentType>Audio</ContentType>
            <isScrambled>0</isScrambled>
        </pid>
        <pid>
            <pidNumber>319</pidNumber>
            <ContentType>Audio</ContentType>
            <isScrambled>0</isScrambled>
        </pid>
    </profile>
</entry>
```

**Python**

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("file.xml")
profile = tree.find("profile")

for pid in profile.findall(".//pid"):
    nbr = int(pid.find("pidNumber").text)
    if 302 <= nbr <= 310:
        profile.remove(pid)

tree.write('out.xml')
```

**out.xml**

```
<entry>
    <title>TEST1</title>
    <profile>
        <title>Default</title>
        <pid>
            <pidNumber>1880</pidNumber>
            <ContentType>PMT</ContentType>
            <isScrambled>0</isScrambled>
        </pid>
        <pid>
            <pidNumber>201</pidNumber>
            <ContentType>Video</ContentType>
            <isScrambled>0</isScrambled>
        </pid>
        <pid>
            <pidNumber>301</pidNumber>
            <ContentType>Audio</ContentType>
            <isScrambled>0</isScrambled>
        </pid>
        <pid>
            <pidNumber>319</pidNumber>
            <ContentType>Audio</ContentType>
            <isScrambled>0</isScrambled>
        </pid>
    </profile>
</entry>
```

Another option is to use lxml instead of ElementTree. This will give you full xpath support so you can do the comparison in a predicate.

Using the `file.xml` input above, the following python produces the same `out.xml` output as above.

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("file.xml")
for pid in tree.xpath(".//pid[pidNumber[. >= 302][310 >= .]]"):
    pid.getparent().remove(pid)

tree.write("out.xml")
```

A third option is to use XSLT (thanks for the suggestion @Parfait)...

**Python**

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("file.xml")
xslt = etree.parse("test.xsl")
new_tree = tree.xslt(xslt)
new_tree.write_output("out_xslt.xml")
```

**XSLT 1.0** (test.xsl)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pid[pidNumber[. >= 302][310 >= .]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Again this produces the same results as the other options using the same input.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the alternative option of using lxml. That looks much simpler.

Comment: Of course too, XSLT can remove the needed elements without any `for` loops. And @DanielHaley can show that answer too. Python's `lxml` can run XSLT 1.0 scripts.

Comment: @Parfait - Good idea. I'll add that third option. Thanks for the suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
enter code hereimport re
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
regex = r"[3][0-1][02-9]"
getpid = root.getiterator("pid")

for item in getpid:
    pidnum = item.find('.//pidNumber')
    pidnum = pidnum.text
    match = re.findall(regex, pidnum)
    match = ''.join(match)
    if pidnum == match:
        item.clear()
# create a new XML file with the results
tree.write('out.xml')
```

Thanks everyone.